# Interaction Plots unclear

Tags: r, data-visualization, interaction, interpretation

I want to plot an interaction in R, but I get a quite confusing plot that does not appear parsomonious at all.

The code I used to create it is:

```
interaction.plot(x.factor = mydata$cN, 
                 trace.factor = mydata$cDA,
                 response = mydata$tDep)
```

Could it maybe be a problem with graph scalling? What do you think it could be? How could I make the interpretation of this plot easier?

[image]

Comment: Using different colors for the different lines might help some.   Also, getting rid of the lines and just using points (boxes or circles) where there is actual data might help.  Putting fewer categories (those in the legend) might help.

Comment: Line charts on nonlinear axes (the x axis here) typically are meaningless or deceitful. This nonlinearity does suggest, though, that you are treating numerical variables `cN` and `cDA` as factors, thereby using $9\times 10-1=89$ parameters to model them (assuming you included the interactions).  That's about as unparsimonious as you can get!  Did you intend to do that?